# Bug is jquery datatables? $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable not working right

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
function CreateTable(tableId, dataUrl) {
    var isdataTable = $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable($('#' + tableId));
    console.log('isdataTable: ' + isdataTable); 

    table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({ 
        ...
        ...
    });
}
```

Now in some cases I see that I get 'true' in isdataTable, and still it initializes the datatable without error...

I don't understand, is that possible?

Comment: "i" should be capitalized when used to refer to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No need for passing a jQuery instance to [**`isDataTable()`**](http://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable%28%29) - just pass a *selector*. You are not showing the initialization options, but if you have `destroy : true` you can reinitialize a dataTables instance without errors :

```js
function CreateTable(tableId, dataUrl) {
    var isDataTable = $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#' + tableId);
    console.log('isDataTable: ' + isDataTable); 
    table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({ 
       destroy : true
    });
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lgy0m45L/**

Otherwise you'll need to evaluate `isDataTable` in order to avoid ugly alerts :

```js
function CreateTable(tableId, dataUrl) {
    var isDataTable = $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#' + tableId);
    console.log('isDataTable: ' + isDataTable); 
    if (!isDataTable) { 
        table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({ });
    }    
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6bo7r0kk/**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. This appears to be a bug in the angular-datatables-renderer.js file. Change the line in the file that reads `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable` to `$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: `$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable()` is method for older DataTables library version 1.9, newer DataTables 1.10 uses `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just noticed this was causing problems in 1.10.5. There was a bug in the `isDataTable()` method that is now resolved. See [Bug is jquery datatables? $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable not working right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798062/bug-is-jquery-datatables-fn-datatable-isdatatable-not-working-right)